# Addressing an xml value in enrich Mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I want to address an xml value in the Xpath field within the enrich mediator in order to customize an API response. My xml input is as follow:

```xml
<member>
    <name>ABC</name>
    </value>1</value>
</member>
```

I tried to access the 'ABC' value by using this code:

```
$body//member[@name='ABC']
```

but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your XML input is not valid. There is no opening value tag but two closing.
Can you try //member/name/text(),this worked für me.If its not working,then maybe you need to add the namespaces.

Hope that helps.